# golang unmarshal yaml from a vault file

Tags: go, yaml, ansible-vault

With the below code I can get the yaml from the Ansible vault file which results in:

```
---
dbtype: redis
vsad: go0v
```

When attempting to unmarshal the YAML I get only:

```
map[string]string(nil)
```

My desired goal is to unvault the file, edit the data, re-vault the file.

How do I achieve the unmarshal so as to edit the data?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sosedoff/ansible-vault-go"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Props struct {
    values map[string]string
}
func main() {
    str, err := vault.DecryptFile("/tmp/tmpvlt", `.NunY4hb33zWx!)`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    props := Props{}
    err2 := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &props)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",props.values)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do either

```golang
var props map[string]string
```

or

```golang
err2 := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &props.values)
```

In your current code, the unmarshaler cannot access the private field `values`, and even if you make it public by renaming it to `Values`, it would not be filled because your YAML doesn't have a top-level key named `values`.